# Why { } doesn't work any more in Latex?

Tags: support, mathjax

Any idea why  `$\{$`  or `$\}$` doesn't work anymore in latex on Math Stack ? (it seems to work here on meta however) When I write it, just nothing appear. Moreover, since a certain time, I realized that the automatic latex compilation became very slow on the Math Stack. Am I the only one who has this problem ? I have a MacBook Pro, Version Ventura 13.0.1 and Chrome Version 119.0.6045.199

Comment: You are right that if you type `${}$` nothing appears in the preview pane until you put something inside the {}. If you want to see the { and } in maths-mode you have to qualify them as in `$\{\}$`. But just typing `{` and `}` (not in maths-mode) should work.

Comment: I know, in Mast Stack, I write dollars \{ \} dollars, and nothing appear (however, it works here on meta) @PeterPhipps

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35946/72031