# How do I view latex source code in answers or questions as rendered form or images?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Is it normal to see only the latex source code in questions and answers where they are typed?

My perspective:

[image: my perspective]

---

Is there any way to render this into images or some form of intelligible format that I could at a glance understand? I've tried to use online latex compilers and they didn't work too well and threw all sorts of errors - and I have no clue on latex.

P.S. I think this question is more appropriate on meta but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Edit the question then look between the dollar signs.

Comment: Do you have scripts disabled?

Comment: I'm not sure if i have scripts disabled, how do i check?

Comment: Try following the tips outlined [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html)... however it is rather strange that it wouldn't have tried to render straight away.  It is also weird that your user avatar image appears as a broken image link (to the right of the search bar next to the 1).  I suspect this has to do with a security suite or vpn on your machine preventing your browser from loading all necessary resources.

Comment: I'm using chrome and it does show me this: https://i.gyazo.com/9735fd3617c845f1df50d7042bb9c8ea.png which would indicated that i have js enabled for all sites

Comment: Ah, I think i found the problem, my browser cannot access "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML" anything under the domain of cdnjs.cloudflare.com is restricted, i don't know whether if my country has been banned or banned them, I don't have any VPN on.

> This site can’t be reached cdnjs.cloudflare.com refused to connect. 
they say

Comment: This is rather annoying, I found out that using a VPN allows me to load them properly. Which would indicate that I have been banned from accessing anything under https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ for no apparent reasons, not that I know of. Is there any alternatives to render proprely except from using a VPN?

Comment: Hmm... depending on how comfortable you are coding, you could probably make an addon for chrome that dynamically adds `<script src="some-path-to-a-mirror-of-mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>` to the head of the page... if you can find someone hosting the MathJax.js file on a different server than the one you can't access

Comment: I think you can install Mathjax on your device and render the code directly.

Comment: Using a mirror path sounds like a godo idea! Also how do i install it directly to my device @DavidMitra ?

Comment: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/installation.html (I am not sure this will do what's needed...)

Comment: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/advanced/dynamic.html is effectively what I was suggesting.  It still requires knowledge however of a path to a different server hosting MathJax.js which I have yet to find.  As for where to try for a mirrored copy, try the earlier host: cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js

Comment: The offical guide in the comment above indicated that MathJax can be loaded from another CDN using GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey, or users can simply resort to many addons of browsers for redirecting source requests. Loading local copies is, however, not supported due to security reasons.

Comment: Re "local copies" I have not actually tried this myself, but consider the following post: [A super easy way to speedup MathJax loading with LocalCDN add-on](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34170/a-super-easy-way-to-speedup-mathjax-loading-with-localcdn-add-on). As a last resort, you could paste into [Overleaf](http://overleaf.com) or a local install of LaTeX...

Answer (score -1):

Just right click to get mathjax menu and make it render stuff in HTML+CSS. [image]

Comment: This is not the solution, because the OP cannot access this dropdown menu if they cannot reach a copy of mathjax from the server, cf comments to the Question

Comment: Okay, yes, his cloudflare is banned.