# Mathjax not working on Chrome 99.0.4844.51 (64 bit) Windows 7

Tags: support, mathjax

This problem has started ever since I joined MSE (it never loaded on my computer!) Only recently I tried to troubleshoot the problem as I started using MSE more. I have tried everything mentioned in other questions/threads for example I tried clearing cache but the problem still remained, I tried accessing the site via http instead of https and I am getting redirected to https. When I open the console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J on my computer I get the following[image: console when I load MSE]

Can someone guide me out of this issue?
EDIT - It works on the official mathjax site (the equations are loading there but not on mathstackexchange or any other site for that matter
Regards

Comment: Have you tried running in a different browser, in private mode, safe mode, or otherwise without your ad blockers and whatever add-ons?

Comment: it looks like you cannot even connect to google? Is google banned in your country? Or are you blocking google-analytics.com?

Comment: Maybe it’s time to use an operating system that has not hit its end-of-life over two years ago.

Comment: The error messages in your screenshot indicate that dns is not working properly. This is an issue with your internet service provider. You may try changing the dns server (say to [one offered by Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)).

Comment: OK, well I have no idea how to fix the problem, but maybe you can try using [LocalCDN](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34170/a-super-easy-way-to-speedup-mathjax-loading-with-localcdn-add-on)

Comment: @CalvinKhor I used the CDN extension on Chrome store and it works! Thank you so very much!

Comment: wow! glad to help!

Comment: There is an underlying issue.  Presumably, the OP (i.e. original poster) is continuing to use Windows 7 because they did not like Windows 8, and wished to avoid all of the [Windows 10 -- Windows 11] nonsense.  A somewhat extreme (but free) remedy is Linux Mint (Cinnamon desktop) that resembles the Windows desktop.  I abandoned Windows and went to Linux to avoid the Microsoft nonsense.